# $\displaystyle f\colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a strictly monotone continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the following problem:

> Suppose $f\colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a strictly monotone continuous function,differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $e^b f(a)=e^a f(b).$ Then there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that

1. $f'(c)=0$
2. $f(c)f'(c)=-1$
3. $f(c)=f'(c)$
4. None of the above holds.

I have to determine which of the following options hold.

I guess I have to apply Rolle's theorem but for this I have to construct a function so that it can satisfy  the condition $e^b f(a)=e^a f(b),$ along with first two conditions. But I could not do it. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = e^x$.

Comment: Consider $g(x) = f(x)/e^x$. This satisfies $g(a)=g(b)$. Use Rolle's theorem now to show the third statement. The first two are not true as shown by the counter example by Isaac above.

Comment: Finally, use Rolle's theorem.

Comment: @ronno I have moved my comment to an answer, but I am having some trouble posting to the chat room. Maybe you can upvote this yourself and get this question removed from unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $g(x) = f(x)/e^x$. This satisfies $g(a) = g(b)$. Use Rolle's theorem now to show the third statement. The first two are true as shown by the counter example by Isaac in the comment above ($f(x) = e^x$).